# Arduino - Using NPN transistor as a switch to pull-up/down analog pin

Tags: transistors, analog, npn, pins

Let me start by saying that I am not an EE, and my knowledge in Electronics is basic, so please bear with me and be patient if, initially I am bending a few rules.

In Epee fencing, a touch is awarded when contact is made at the end of a weapon's tip: when A (Analog Pin A0) and B (Analog Pin A1) are in contact, both A0 and A1 read 2,5V and a touch is awarded.

In Foil fencing, I need to establish that a fencer has been touched on its Lame (a conductive jacket). Therefore, in addition to the Analog functionality, I also need to implement a Capacitive sensor on the A0 pin. The Cap sensor uses a digital Pin (D4 in Diagram) to charge the Capacitor via a large (1M) resistor and reads the Voltage/status of a Receiving Pin (here A0).

The A0 pin is therefore used both for Analog and Digital readings purposes. This is the source of my issue, and why I am here.

I have no choice but to share the analog pin A0 for both analog and digital read purposes (there is only one line A). I have established that I cannot read the Analog levels and the Cap sensor output at the same time, without exposing myself to adverse side effects (wrongfully sending 5V to the Cap during the Cap sensor operation when A&B are in contact being one of them...). I, therefore, perform these tasks simultaneously:

1. Sampling both Analog A0 and A1 Pins (Analog ON/Digital OFF),
2. Sampling Analog A0 as a Digital INPUT (Analog OFF/Digital ON),

My primary concern is to achieve some form of isolation of the Cap sensor when in operation: this is to avoid the 1K resistors getting in the way of my capacitive sensor sampling, and CRUCIALLY, the A1 pin (connected to 5V via a 1K resistor) not charging the Cap during a touch sensing operation, thus destroying the significance of the values sampled.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDpjBS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I also critically need to avoid the limits of the Cap Sensing circuit extending beyond its absolute necessary boundaries, which is not the case if the tip is depressed, or if the 1K resistor is pulling the A0 to GND, preventing the Capacitor from being charged properly.

So, I have a few questions:

- In the diagram, I show what I THINK the solution to this problem is (but I am not saying it IS the solution).
- Do you think I am right?
- Am I going in the right direction using NPN Transistors? Are they used correctly?
- If you did not use this method, What would the correct circuit be, etc,

Thank you very much in advance to all of you for helping me out. Don't hesitate to ask for more details.

Note: changed the schematics to use Q2 as a PNP following a suggestion from 'Captain Normal' below.

Comment: You write that the ADC readings are not what you expected. Have you measured the voltages at the pin with a multimeter?  Note the NPN is not a perfect switch. For ex, when "ON" the voltage across the transistor is not ZERO.

Comment: These problems should be entirely avoidable as your circuit seems more complicated than the task requires.  Why not put the resistor in series with the analog pin and use that as an *output* then switch it to analog input mode?

Comment: Thank you Chris. I understand that the circuit might not be perfect. So what would you recommend to implement an ON/OFF switch on these Resistors, bearing in mind that I must be able to decouple them from the circuit so I can use the Analog Pin for another purpose (the Capacitive Sensor)?

Comment: Thanks Mike. Yes, I have measured voltages with a multimeter, and yes, VCC is not 5V. I also understand that the NPN is not a perfect switch. My question then, is how can I achieve a (near) perfect switch and have my circuit behave as if the NPN where physical switches which can be turned on and off electronically? I need to turn them ON when I measure both A0 and A1, and if there is no contact between the Tips of the Pins, they should return 0V and 5V. In turn, when there is a contact, I expect both Analog Pins to return close to 2.5V (Voltage divider from the 1K resistors). Hope this helps.

Comment: **Do not repost** - use the `edit` button to fix this question.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion Chris. I have taken your remark onboard and edited the question with more detail and background (also to address the very unwelcomed X-Y remark...). I would GREATLY appreciate if you could take another look. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As Chris said, it seems you are getting to complicated. The reason why someone said it was an X-Y problem is that this is your idea to the solution and it may not be the right one but without knowing underlying requirements it is hard for people to help. For example, what is the capacitive sensor for?

Comment: Drew you are absolutely correct, it might not be the right solution. If you need to know, I need the Cap Sensor to detect that the guard of Weapon 1 has not been touched whilst the Tip of Weapon 2 is depressed, which would indicate a non valid hit. I don't think I am too complex: the problem is complex, and it is always difficult to simplify a question, especially asked to experts. If you allow me this remark made in good spirit, if you give everything, people say you are too complex, and if you say less, they say you're X-Ying them...

Answer (score 1):

> So, I have a questions: - Am I going in the right direction using NPN Transistors? - What would the correct circuit be, etc.

Measuring the capacitance of a real-world object by charging via a 1M resistor is probably not the right approach as the currents involved are very small and the circuit is not likely to measure reliably. Further, connecting external objects directly to Arduino pins is probably not a good idea due to the chances of ESD destroying your Arduino after some amount of use. For those reasons I think you need to first take a little step back.

I suggest starting with measuring the capacitance by using an oscillator whose frequency will vary depending upon the capacitance. You can then measure the frequency via a circuit that converts frequency to voltage for your ADC. Circuits for both of these you should be able to find elsewhere.

That done, you should be able to build a detector for the sensor contact on top of your capacitance detector. You will have several discrete states of contact for your various sensors - eg no contact, weapon A contact with lame B, weapon contact with wrist guard, etc. Draw a table for how the your circuit behaves when the sensors are in each and every possible state. You may have enough "information" in the existing circuit, or you may need to augment it slightly.

I hope this helps point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you, Captain Normal. I had not thought about ESD. That's a very valid point. It stays that whichever alternative routes I am taking for the measurement of the Cap Sensor, this must be done being sure that the the Cap sensor remains totally neutral to the Analog section of the circuit, and especially, the fact that A1 is pull-up to 5V... And this is where I struggle. Thanks again for your contribution.

Comment: Captain normal, your Oscillator suggestion is bloody brilliant... Can you recommend parts I could use for this project? (bearing in mind I am a hobbyist and not an EE...)

Comment: There are many ways to do it, but my first thought in your case would be to use a 556 timer IC, which is a duel 555 - pun intended due to your application ;-). You can use one timer as an oscillator, replacing the capacitor to ground with your sensor, and the second timer as a one-shot triggered by each falling edge of the oscillating signal. Filter the output of the second timer with a simple RC to convert it to a voltage. Start with the Wikipedia page for the "555 timer IC", in particular the "Astable" section for the oscillator and the "Monostable" section for the conversion to voltage.

Comment: Brilliant. A BIG thank you Captain Normal. I am not sure I understand everything you just said, but this first "normal" answer I got here so far...

Comment: Ah - you updated your OP, probably as I answered it. I see what you're doing - not bad! I would however stand by my suggestion for capacitive measurement, get that going, then work out how best to detect the tip switch on top of that without interfering with it too much - which should not be too hard. Do you have access to an oscilloscope? Get a 555 timer going as an oscillator, then swap out the capacitor for your sensor (or add your sensor in parallel to it) and see if you can get it oscillating at different frequencies depending upon what the sensor is doing. Then go from there.

Comment: If the 555 approach does not work (eg the capacitance is too low which will mean your resistors are too large eg > 100k max) you may need a different type of oscillator (eg based on a comparator - you should be able to find example circuits).

Comment: Captain Normal, I am studying the Oscillator appr. and the use of a 555 for sure. This may take me some time though as this is now pushing my skills way beyond my area of comfort (...). Now: I am not too worried about having to measure too little capacitance or resistor size (right now, I think 100k is plenty as I need a digital signal only), but rather how much time one 555 cycle takes with this resistor (T=1.1RC still holds ?). I also have nightmares about my 5V connection in A1 interfering with the charge/discharge process and I am not sure the schematics above are working to avoid this...

Comment: btw, measuring Capacitance via an Oscillator rather than brute force charge/dischage is an elegant approach, and as a french engineer, I always love elegant... but my problem is SPEED. My time budget is <1ms: So, I have allocated less than 700micros to perform one Cap. Sensing cycle, and still have to read one of my analog pins. If the tip is depressed during the 555 Cycle, 5V gets in the way interfering with the 555 and nothing good can  happen from that...

Comment: and to answer your other question re oscilloscope, I don't have access to one. Again, if you can recommend a not-so-expensive one... (but yet again, cheap means just that usually...)

Comment: You haven't marked the capacitance you're trying to measure in your circuit, so it's hard to comment. I had assumed capacitance to ground as a starting point. If it's not this then you will probably need a different oscillator design. My suggestion was based around continuous measurement of the capacitance and tip switch, rather than two modes. If you really need to switch modes every 1ms or so then an oscillator will not easily work for the measurement.

Comment: If capacitance to ground is not what you're measuring, rather the capacitance across the switch, then a circuit similar to what you have is possibly more appropriate. In that case I would suggest replacing Q2 with a PNP so the circuit is symmetrical. You could consider using two MOSFETs, or a complimentary MOSFET pair - MOSFETs generally are easier to use for switching between two states than bipolar transistors.

Comment: An oscilloscope can be extremely useful. For your purposes the cheapest one you can get your hands on will most likely be fine, as you will be dealing with audio frequencies. Useful as a cheapo alternative for monitoring audio frequency oscillators is a crystal earpiece - it can also be useful in addition to an oscilloscope because our ears are extremely good at hearing frequency changes.

Comment: Again Captain, a big thank you for your suggestions and remarks. There are two Capacitance levels I am trying to measure. The one in focus here (an epee or foil guard) is in the 200-500nF. I also have a larger one (the lame, ore more conductive and way larger) which I am not mentioning here (in order to simplify) which is 50-400uF, but I'll have to confirm these figures as they are just a guess right now and vary massively with individual equipment (rust, sweat, tear in fibres, connections and general tidyness, dirt, etc...).

Comment: Re. the Oscilloscope, would this one be suitable:   https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B07B8K8671/ref=asc_df_B07B8K867157034015/?tag=googshopuk-21&creative=22146&creativeASIN=B07B8K8671&linkCode=df0&hvadid=310879398178&hvpos=1o2&hvnetw=g&hvrand=1966331166266681248&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9045954&hvtargid=pla-567435273562

Comment: I can't comment on particular oscilloscopes, but there is nothing wrong with the specs of that one for your purposes. Pretty much anything that functions will do the job well enough, being to show you what is going on with your circuit.

Comment: Ok. Roger that. Thanks for the remark on the PNP also. I have amended my schematics to include it. Now on MOSFETs, this is a totally unknown area to me and I have read that the selection of a MOSFET compared to that of a BJT is a factor more complex. One more thing I will have to study... And I have jst ordered some 555/556 ICs to explore measuring Capacitance with Oscillators but I am still trying to figure out why you suggested I use a 556 dual IC, if you could elaborate on that, when you have a chance.

Comment: One oscillator will produce something like a square wave output with a frequency varying with capacitance. The frequency means for you the number of falling edges per second. The second timer is configured as a one-shot (eg producing 1ms pulses) triggered of each falling edge of the first. So the faster you get the triggers, the more 1ms pulses you get per second. You put this through an RC filter to get a voltage that varies linearly with frequency. You can also buy chips that do frequency to voltage conversion, but I'd use a 556 to keep it simple with one IC.

Comment: Well, thanks a bunch, Captain. If that's not too much trouble, I might have to revert back to you at some stage as I suspect I will need some guidance on how to build this oscillator (circuit and code). Let me say that you've already been a big help.